# Add typescript file tree to angular cli build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-cli

I've created an Angular CLI project, and added on Express to make a web server out of it. My tree looks like this:

```
/common
/server
    server.ts
    /routes
/src
    (Angular CLI generated stuff)
    tsconfig.json
(other stuff)
tsconfig.json
```

To build, I do an "npm run tsc", which compiles the TypeScript code in /server and /common, and I can successfully run my server (i.e. routes).

The problem is the Angular web pages under /src -- when I run "ng build", it can't find the /common directory (which contains things like interfaces and helper libraries used by both the server and the client).

So, in my Angular CLI configuration, how do I add the /common directory, such that the "ng build" command finds it as if it was located as /src/common? Is there a way to add an additional source code location? Note that if I *copy* the content of /common to /src/common, then everything works fine. Of course, that's not what I want to do.

John

Comment: I would try with a symlink.

Comment: Is there a better solution besides a symlink? I tried that path, but Git and Windows don't seem to play nice with symbolic links.